# Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference (Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s))

Tags: multithreading, segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp, valgrind

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
  SUBROUTINE GRAD(tasklist_GRAD,ww,pas,cpt ,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,u_prime_plus,&
        &taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab)
    INTEGER ::i,j,k,ff,pas
    INTEGER,intent(inout)::cpt,cpt1,nb_element,ww
    real*8  :: dt,dx
    integer ,allocatable, dimension(:),intent(inout) ::p_element
    REAL*8 ,allocatable, dimension(:),intent(inout) :: u_prime,u_prime_moins, u_prime_plus,taux,grad_x_u,&
         &grad_t_u,grad_t_f,grad_x_f,flux,sm
    real*8,allocatable,dimension(:),intent(inout) :: ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_moins,ux_plus
    REAL*8 ,allocatable, dimension(:,:),intent(inout) ::tab0,tab
    integer::num_thread,nthreads
    integer, external :: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS
    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::threads_list
    integer,dimension(30)::threads_list_all
    integer,dimension(3)::threads_list_part1
    integer::threads_list_part2    
    integer,dimension(16)::threads_list_part3
    type(tcb)::self

    !-----------Calcul des gradients de x

    
    Choisircese: select case (ww)

    case(0)  !  Old CESE
       tasklist_GRAD(1)%f_ptr => u_prime_1 !1
       tasklist_GRAD(2)%f_ptr => u_prime_droite_1 !2
       tasklist_GRAD(3)%f_ptr => u_prime_gauche_1 !3

       !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,nthreads) &
       !$OMP SHARED(tasklist_GRAD,threads_list,threads_list_all,tasks_ready_master) &
       !$OMP SHARED(threads_list_part1,threads_list_part2,threads_list_part3)

       num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
       nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
       
       !Thread Application Master
       !$OMP SINGLE
       if (num_thread==1) then 
          do ff=1,3
             if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true. ) then
                tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff) 
             end if
          end do

          do ff=1,3
             if (associated(tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true.) then
                tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
             end if
          end do          
       end if
       !$OMP END SINGLE

       !Thread Master
       !$OMP SINGLE
       if (num_thread==0) then          
          allocate(threads_list(nthreads-2))
          do ff=1,nthreads-2
             threads_list(ff)=ff+1
          end do

          do ff=1,3,nthreads-2
             if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_READY) then
                threads_list_all(ff:ff+nthreads-3)=threads_list(:)
             end if
          end do
          threads_list_part1=threads_list_all(1:3) 
       end if
       !$OMP END SINGLE 
       !Threads workers
       do ff=1,3
          if (num_thread==threads_list_part1(ff)) then
             !$OMP TASK
             call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,ww,pas,cpt ,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,&
                  &u_prime_plus,taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab)
             !$OMP END TASK
          end if
       end do

       !$OMP END PARALLEL


       if(pas.eq.2)then
          u_prime(2) = tab0(2,2)+dt/2.0d0*grad_x_u(2)!d_t_u(2)
          u_prime(cpt-1) = tab0(cpt-1,2)+dt/2.0d0*grad_t_u(cpt-1)
          u_prime(1) = tab0(1,2)+dt/2.0d0*grad_t_u(1)
          u_prime(cpt) = tab0(cpt,2)+dt/2.0d0*grad_t_u(cpt)

          u_prime_plus(1)= (u_prime(2)-tab(1,2))/(dx/2.0d0)
          u_prime_moins(1)=-(u_prime(1)-tab(1,2))/(dx/2.0d0)
          u_prime_plus(cpt)= (u_prime(cpt)-tab(cpt,2))/(dx/2.0d0)
          u_prime_moins(cpt)= -(u_prime(cpt-1)-tab(cpt,2))/(dx/2.0d0)
       end if
end select choisircese
  END SUBROUTINE GRAD
```

The code is quite long so I only posted the case 0 (a sufficient part to understand the whole subroutine).

In order to compile, I do:

```
gfortran -fopenmp -O3 -g HECESE_openmp.f90
```

In order to execute, I do (I have fixed the number of threads previously):

```
./a.out
```

The error I get is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f0eae2d6700 in ???
#0  0x7f0eae2d6700 in ???
#0  0x7f0eae2d6700 in ???
#1  0x7f0eae2d58a5 in ???
#1  0x7f0eae2d58a5 in ???
#2  0x7f0eadf7520f in ???
#3  0x0 in ???
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

I decided so to use valgrind and I did:

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out
```

and the errors I get are:

```
==10923== Thread 6:
==10923== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10923==    at 0x1153DE: __procedures_MOD_grad._omp_fn.4 (HECESE_openmp.f90:702)
==10923==    by 0x4C81A85: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4F13608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==10923==    by 0x4DCD292: clone (clone.S:95)
==10923==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==10923==    at 0x10B22A: __procedures_MOD_grad (HECESE_openmp.f90:482)
==10923== 
==10923== Thread 1:
==10923== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10923==    at 0x1153DE: __procedures_MOD_grad._omp_fn.4 (HECESE_openmp.f90:702)
==10923==    by 0x4C78E75: GOMP_parallel (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x10BF35: __procedures_MOD_grad (HECESE_openmp.f90:659)
==10923==    by 0x1123CA: MAIN__ (HECESE_openmp.f90:1065)
==10923==    by 0x113E45: main (HECESE_openmp.f90:723)
==10923==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==10923==    at 0x10B22A: __procedures_MOD_grad (HECESE_openmp.f90:482)
==10923== 
==10923== Thread 8:
==10923== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==10923==    at 0x0: ???
==10923==    by 0x4C7BD7A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4C846A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x1153A4: __procedures_MOD_grad._omp_fn.4 (HECESE_openmp.f90:674)
==10923==    by 0x4C81A85: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4F13608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==10923==    by 0x4DCD292: clone (clone.S:95)
==10923==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10923== 

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
==10923== Thread 5:
==10923== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==10923==    at 0x0: ???
==10923==    by 0x4C7BD7A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4C846A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4C81A91: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4F13608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==10923==    by 0x4DCD292: clone (clone.S:95)
==10923==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10923== 
==10923== Thread 1:
==10923== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==10923==    at 0x0: ???
==10923==    by 0x4C7BD7A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4C846A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x4C8304C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==10923==    by 0x10BF35: __procedures_MOD_grad (HECESE_openmp.f90:659)
==10923==    by 0x1123CA: MAIN__ (HECESE_openmp.f90:1065)
==10923==    by 0x113E45: main (HECESE_openmp.f90:723)
==10923==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10923== 
#0  0x487e700 in ???
#1  0x487d8a5 in ???
#2  0x4cf120f in ???
#3  0x0 in ???
==10923== 
==10923== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10923==    at 0x4CF1169: raise (raise.c:46)
==10923==    by 0x4CF120F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so)
==10923== 
==10923== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10923==     in use at exit: 263,919 bytes in 122 blocks
==10923==   total heap usage: 195 allocs, 73 frees, 330,511 bytes allocated
==10923== 
==10923== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10923==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10923==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10923==      possibly lost: 3,344 bytes in 11 blocks
==10923==    still reachable: 260,575 bytes in 111 blocks
==10923==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10923== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10923== 
==10923== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==10923== ERROR SUMMARY: 165 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Can you help me please to find out where all these errors come from ? It was okay until I added the `$!OMP SINGLE` and retired the `$!OMP BARRIER`.

Comment: Use `gfortran -g -Wall  -fcheck=all`. See [mcve], a full self-contained piece of code is necessary to be able to help you. Yes, it requires some effort to prepare such a minimal code. People often find the error themselves in the process of preparing it.

Comment: *Either*       if (num_thread==0) then         *or* Single. Not both. Think about the logic

Comment: @IanBush according to your answer, I think that I will get rid of the `!$OMP SINGLE` because if I retire the filter `if (num_thread==0)` then I won't be sure that the master (thread number 0) will do the work. Am I right ?

Comment: Just to clarify my first comment, those options will make it also easier to make sense of your valgrind output in the future.  Especially the `-g` flag. And the `-fcheck` flag may help you to find the problem without even having to use valgrind. Even if you got the solution quickly today, these should help you many times in the future.

Comment: Why do you particular want the master in particular to do it? As far as I can see as long as one thread does it it doesn't matter which thread does it. In OpenMP if you can avoid giving specific threads specific tasks you tend to end up with a better performant (and often more readable) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

```
       !$OMP SINGLE
       if (num_thread==0) then          
...
          threads_list_part1=threads_list_all(1:3) 
       end if
       !$OMP END SINGLE 
       !Threads workers
       do ff=1,3
          if (num_thread==threads_list_part1(ff)) then
```

The first thread that reaches this code will go into the `single` block. All other threads will then skip over it and wait at the implicit barrier at the end until the thread that entered the block finishes its work. If, ***and only if***, the thread that enters the block is thread number 0 will the array `threads_list_part1` get initialised. If any other thread enters the block it will not be initialised. You have no guarantee which thread enters the block so what you are seeing is a thread with number *not* zero being the first to reach the single block. Probable solution: just get rid of the `if (num_thread==0) then` and similarly for the other single block previous to it.

That said having seen what you are doing an even more OpenMP way of doing it might be to use parallel sections, about the first time I have ever seen that this might be a sensible thing to do.

Comment: I think the `single` construct will be needed to make sure that thread that do not execute the initialization will wait for the one thread to have completed initialization.

Comment: @MichaelKlemm I think that I will get rid of the `!$OMP SINGLE` because if I retire the filter `if (num_thread==0)` then I won't be sure that the master (thread number 0) will do the work. Am I right ? Are we okay that  `!$OMP SINGLE`  and `if (num_thread==0) then ` +  `!$OMP BARRIER`do the same thing ?

Comment: Yes. but you can use `master` and then have a `barrier` right after it to catch the skipping threads.